# end iterator and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, unix, iterator, segmentation-fault

if we take this example :

```
std::map<int,foo*> intmap;
fillMap(intmap);

// I will force this to end(), in real life this could be a "find" output
std::map<int,foo*>::iterator iter = intmap.end(); 
if(iter->second != 0)
    iter->second->whatever();
```

I am having the segmentation fault (which is expected, the example is not checking "iter != intmap.end()"
 on purpose) on the "whatever()" call but not on the "->second" null pointer check : is it the expected behavior ? will this seg fault systematically on the "whatever()" call or is it dependent on specific run time memory conditions ?

Thanks in advance for your comments.
Giacomo

Answer (score 6):

Dereferencing `end()` and past-end iterators for STL containers is Undefined Behavior. There is nothing you can call *expected*. Everything can occur, it even could work.
It could depend on so much many factors like compiler/libs/OS version, run-time environment state, debug/release build etc. So you never should assume what will occur if you do dirty forbidden things.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dereference an "end" iterator. Remember that `iter->`is roughly the same as `(*iter).`; that is, there is a dereference.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing `end()` iterator is an undefined behavior. It may or may not crash.

You must check the return value of `find` like this:

```
if(iter != intmap.end())
   iter->second->whatever();
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of dereferencing a past-the-end iterator is of course undefined behaviour, so there is no guarantee what it will do.

However, it can be instructive (and useful in debugging scenarios) to consider what is likely to happen.  A typical implementation of associative containers is as a binary tree of nodes, where each node contains pointers to the `next` and `previous` nodes in iteration order, and iterators are thin wrappers around a pointer to a node.  Similarly, `list` is implemented as a doubly linked list where each node contains pointers to the `next` and `previous` nodes.  Since the past-the-end iterator needs to be decrementable, the simplest implementation is for it point to a node that always exists and whose `previous` pointer points to the last node in the container.

Because this past-the-end node always needs to exist, even for an empty container, the simplest implementation is to put it inside the container class itself, and most library implementations will do this.  As a result, its storage is automatic (function-local) storage, and it will be default-constructed so dereferencing the past-the-end iterator will give stack garbage.

We can check this by comparing pointers:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    std::cout << &m << ' ' << &*m.end() << ' ' << &m + 1 << '\n';
}

0xbf990034 0xbf990048 0xbf99004c
```

As you can see, the storage for the past-the-end node is contained within the `map`'s stack footprint.